# What is com.qualcomm.qcrilmsgtunnel

Tags: nexus-5

What this **com.qualcomm.qcrilmsgtunnel** does. I stopped it service and process nothing really happened. I restarted the phone and it is back running. Anybody know what this app does. My phone is Nexus 5, 4.4.3.

Comment: This process eats my battery faster than anything else on the phone. Whenever my battery seems to be dropping faster than usual, sure enough this process is running. I pop into developer tools / services and kill it. It doesn't seem to have any other impact on the phone except draining the battery.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its the stock phone dialer app.

Included packages

> **com.qualcomm.qcrilmsgtunnel**
>
> SIM toolkit
>
> Phone/Messaging storage
>
> Phone

If you have enabled 'Fast Dormancy' on a device it may cause a spike in activity / battery use for this process, it appears to be a confilict with this option.